# Correct way to validate config entities?

Tags: 8, entities, forms

In Drupal 8, how do I validate a ConfigEntity? I tried adding constraints, but then I found out this only works for ContentEntity, not ConfigEntity.

My ConfigEntity has 2 fields, and the options of the second field should be limited based on what's selected in the first.

Through Drupals #ajax mechanism I can limit the items in the second dropdown - that all works. However, with Javascript disabled or when creating the ConfigEntity programmatically, someone can still select a wrong value for the second dropdown, that doesn't work with the first dropdown selection. I checked ConfigEntityBase but couldn't find anything related to validation.

Comment: I guess I could override ConfigEntityBase::preSave() and throw an error perhaps?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2636066 :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how your config-entities are created.
If the only way to create them is via a form, then you could just override the `validateForm` method in your form to ensure the entity is valid. In this context the entity should be available by running this code

```
$form_state->cleanValues();
$this->entity = $this->buildEntity($form, $form_state);
```

This is what content entity forms do (see `\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm::validateForm`).

However if you expect your entities to be added programatically or via REST and you need lower-level validation, then you could add a `validate` method to you entity and call this from the preSave method. Having it available as a public method (`validate`) would allow other consumers of your API to check if the entity was valid before they called `save`, thus avoiding the exception.

In terms of the contents of the `validate` method, you have lots of options. You could try and piggy-back onto core's constraint system - which uses plugins to define constraints. Or you could keep it simple and just return an array of errors. Finally you could keep use a middle-ground and just integrate with the validator component in the Symfony way, which would at least keep your `validate` return consistent with those for Content entities - something like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

/**
 * Validates my config entity.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList 
 *   List of violations. Empty if valid.
 */
public function validate() {
  $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    ->addMethodMapping('loadValidatorMetadata')
    ->getValidator();
  return $validator->validate($this);
}

/**
 * Defines validation rules for this config entity.
 */
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata) {
  // Same validator rules.
  // Add your own as required.
  // Note this is static, so you don't have $this in scope.
  $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('someProperty', new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => 'Some property cannot be blank']));
  // But if you add a validation callback, you can operate in the context
  // of an instance.
  $metadata->addConstraint(new Assert\Callback(['methods' => ['someValidationCallback']]));
}

/**
 * Validation callback for some field.
 */
public function someValidationCallback(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
  if ($this->something === 'something it should not be') {
      $context->buildViolation("Can't let you do that Dave.")
      ->atPath('something')
      ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about when the entity is a core config entity? How would you add constraints then?